# Why Angular not binding values from dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Here i have two dropdown list when i select both the dropdown & click on button that values should Bind the values.**
**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="AdminCntrl">
    <input type="button" ng-click="BtnBindDrp()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Bind">    
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="Date">
     <option value="-1">Select Date</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="Year">
        <option value="-1">Select Year</option> <option value="2001">2001</option> <option value="2002">2002</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

**Controller.Js**

```
  $scope.BtnBindDrp = function () {
          var sss = {
            Date: $scope.Date,
            Year: $scope.Year}
        var seri = AdminServices.GetBindvales(sss);
         }
```

**Service.Js**

```
   this.GetBindvales = function (sss) {
        var ss = $http({
            url: '/Department/Date',
            method: 'Get',
            data: JSON.stringify(sss),
            content: { 'content-type': 'application/Json' }
        })
        return ss;
    }
```

**MvcController**

```
 public JsonResult Date(int Date, int Year)
        {
            return new JsonResult { };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In service you used JSON.stringify for sss object element. sss is already an object. Don't need to request your server like a string value. And In html to controller data bind perfectly happening from this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/AAWMMtymdZtWdRp4d6Z6?p=preview) please see at in console for the result.  I think at service to Mvccontroller data binding It's not the perfect way you try. Please describe details where is the problem for your data binding issue.

```
this.GetBindvales = function (sss) {
        var ss = $http({
            url: '/Department/Date',
            method: 'Get',
            data: JSON.stringify(sss),
            content: { 'content-type': 'application/Json' }
        })
        return ss;
    }
```